# same variable referenced when creating variable

Tags: powershell, azure

Still fairly new to using Powershell variables and got a bit confused trying to understand it's syntax and functionality.

On [Azure's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-manage-vm) on creating a new VM, it declares the $VM variable, then uses that same variable within the next variable creation:

```
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $vm -Windows -ComputerName myVM -Credential $cred -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $vm -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsServer -Offer WindowsServer -Skus 2016-Datacenter -Version latest
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm -Name myOsDisk -DiskSizeInGB 128 -CreateOption FromImage -Caching ReadWrite
```

What I'm stuck on is what's going on behind the scenes when creating variables in this fashion.  Is the $vm variable being overwritten each time?  If I 'run' $vm on the powershell console at a later time, will it be able to run this sequence or will it throw an error since the first 2 instances of $vm are no longer around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the $vm variable being overwritten each time?

`$vm` have many attributs, each Azure powershell will add some information (not the same) to it, so the variable `$vm` will not being overwritten.

You can print it like this:

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName myVM -VMSize Standard_D1
PS C:\windows\system32> $vm | fl *


ResourceGroupName        :
Id                       :
VmId                     :
Name                     : myVM
Type                     :
Location                 :
LicenseType              :
Tags                     :
AvailabilitySetReference :
DiagnosticsProfile       :
Extensions               :
HardwareProfile          : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Models.HardwareProfile
InstanceView             :
NetworkProfile           :
OSProfile                :
Plan                     :
ProvisioningState        :
StorageProfile           :
DisplayHint              : Compact
Identity                 :
Zones                    :
FullyQualifiedDomainName :
RequestId                :
StatusCode               : 0
```

Then use run other commands will add some information to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That clears things up quite a bit.  Thanks!  But does that mean $vm is not a standard variable?  I imagine I can't just do something similar with any variable I create.  Are there other variables that hold multiple attributes like this?

Comment: @enterprised1 Yes, `$vm` not a standard variable, you can use `$vm | gm` to check it, type name is `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.Models.PSVirtualMachine`.

Comment: Awesome!  One last question - Is there a way to find other variables (or get a list) that function this way?

Comment: @enterprised1 Based on my knowledge, no. there are not the same Azure resource.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is updating it with each subsequent call.
The `$vm` is created with something like:

```
$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig ...
```

and updated with the other calls like:

```
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $vm ...    
$vm = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $vm ...
$vm = Set-AzureRmVMBootDiagnostics -VM $vm ...
```

As long as you do not overwrite it somewhere else, you can use it wherever you like later in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Each command that you show outputs an Azure Virtual Machine object. When you precede the command with `$vm =` that variable is assigned to the output of the command issued. You can use any variable (excluding a few special reserved variables) that you want. You could just as easily use `$FileServer =` instead of `$vm =` and it would work just the same, so long as you then refer to `$FileServer` any time that you would have referred to `$vm`.

The original command `$vm = New-AzureRmVMConfig` creates the original Azure Virtual Machine object that is captured by the variable `$vm`. Each successive command modifies that object, and outputs the modified version of the object. Since you capture the output each time you are indeed overwriting the variable each time, and each time it is essentially a slightly modified version of itself.

Just as you can use any variable you want, you do not need to re-use the same variable, and could use a new variable each time like:

```
$BaseVM = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName myVM -VMSize Standard_D1
$VMOS = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $BaseVM -Windows -ComputerName myVM  -Credential $cred -ProvisionVMAgent -EnableAutoUpdate
$VMImage = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $VMOS -PublisherName MicrosoftWindowsServer -Offer WindowsServer -Skus 2016-Datacenter -Version latest
$VMOSDisk = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $VMImage -Name myOsDisk -DiskSizeInGB 128 -CreateOption FromImage -Caching ReadWrite
```

Then at the end you can reference `$VMOSDisk` to see your VM with all of the modifications applied, and even reference it against `$BaseVM` to see what all has changed since you initially declared the object.